# Why Does My Collection Not Add My Cube Correctly?

Tags: collections

I'm new to blender and I was working on something when I tried to make a collection, and I realized instead of moving my cube inside of the collection, it put one cube inside of the collection and made a duplicate outside. Does anyone know why this happened?

**edit:**
I pressed shift+m when making the collection and it linked the object, thank you to the person who answered!

[image]

Comment: maybe you've press shift M instead of M when creating the new collection? Shift M will keep a linked version of the object

Comment: that appears to be the problem, thank you!

Comment: Please put an upvote for @moonboots

Answer (score 0):

You've pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> instead of <kbd>M</kbd> when creating the new collection. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> will keep a linked version of the object.